# Unable to identify workspaces when running TFS merge command

Tags: command-line, tfs

When I run the command `tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl`, I see that I have three workspaces named `Apple`, `Banana`, and `Cherry` on my local computer.

I change my current directory to the folder that contains the folders for these workspaces, and I run the command `tf merge /candidate Apple Banana`.

However, I receive the error message `Exactly two items (source and target) are required.  Either local or server paths may be used.` So I run the merge command again, but this time I specify the full paths to the folders for `Apple` and `Banana` respectively. Again, I see the same error message.

What am I doing wrong? How can I merge `Apple` into `Banana` through the command line?

Answer (score 1):

The [tf merge](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-command) command is not used to merge 2 workspaces, it is used to merge 2 branches in TFS. To know more about TFS Branch and Merge, please refer to [this document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-branches-isolate-risk-team-foundation-version-control).

If you want to merge/combine 2 workspaces (from `Apple` to `Banana`), maybe you could follow these steps:

1. In Visual Studio, switch to `Apple` workspace first , check in all changes under `Apple`.
2. Then switch to `Banana` workspace, Right-click team project and choose **Get Latest Version**. Then you will get all changes just submitted from `Apple`.
3. If you edit the same files in `Apple` and `Banana`, you may get conflicts now. Just use the Merge tool to merge the conflicts.

After you solve the conflicts, the Apple are merged into Banana.